# MySQL database partition

Tags: mysql, sql, partitioning

I have a huge table `name, date, source, detail, views`. `name, date, source, detail` are together as PK. `source` is originally ENUM type.

Now I plan to partition the table. I plan to change the `source` to `sourceid (INT)`, and `PARTITION BY LIST (sourceid)`. I have tested on another small table.

My question is, do I need some addition process (e.g., prune) to make the later `SELECT` command faster? AND will simple `SELECT * FROM tb WHERE sourceid = 1` command be faster (only lookup the right partition instead of the whole table)?

Answer (score 0):

> do I need some addition process (e.g., prune) to make the later `SELECT` command faster?

Using partitions won't magically make SELECTs faster.

> Will simple `SELECT * FROM tb WHERE sourceid = 1` command be faster (only lookup the right partition instead of the whole table)?

Will MySQL analyze the WHERE clause to decide which partitions to read from? Yes.

Will this be faster than having an index on `sourceid`? Impossible to say without knowing more about your database.

Comment: What else do you need to know about the database?

Comment: Among other things, it'd depend on the storage engine you're using, the distribution of rows between `sourceid`s, what indexes are present, and any number of MySQL configuration options.